# C# and Modal Windows

Tags: c#, window, modal-dialog

I have the following situation: The main window where some of the data is completed, it is also a button that opens a new modal window where you choose the product and the range of products, I click OK and move on to the next screen where choose the quantity, price, and after approval of the data which I click OK, I want to have access to the data selected in modal windows in the main window, as it can be done using C #?

Comment: Pass your parameters by reference.

Comment: @timmy How... what does that have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something that looks more or less like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 firstPopup = new Form2();
    firstPopup.ShowDialog();
    var someData = firstPopup.SomeValue;

    Form2 secondPopup = new Form2();
    secondPopup.ShowDialog();
    var someOtherData = secondPopup.SomeValue;

    doSomeStuff(someData, someOtherData);
}
```

In this case `SomeValue` is a property on the form with a public getter and a private setter.  It's value will be set sometime before the form is closed.  You can have any number of such properties per form, and any number of forms.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the way that Open, Save As and Folder dialogs work. Take for example the Open File Dialog, once you click OK, you have access to the file that was selected

Suggestion:

In your modal window, set some public properties which hold your data. Set your OK button to set the forms DialogResult to OK, in your parent form you can do the following test (in this instance, DataModel is the data you are trying to access)

```
if(modalWindow.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.DataModel = modalWindow.DataModel;
}
```

Here is some information on how to use DialogResult
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Typically with a Modal window you follow a similar pattern to that used by the OpenFileDialog, where you do something like this:

```
public class MyDialog : Form
{
  public MyResult Result { get { /* code elided */ } }
}
```

I.e, in addition to having the modal form's code - you also expose a public `Result` property of a given type which can provide the data entered on that form's UI (this is better than exposing the controls on the form as it means you are free to change all of that without having to re-code any other forms that depends on it).

You make sure that the `Result` is *guaranteed* to be available *and valid* if the `Ok` or `Yes` (whatever the confirmation button is) button is clicked.  Then you make sure that you set the `DialogResult` of the form accordingly (you can assign one to each button as well - e.g. `DialogResult.Cancel` to a cancel button).

Then when you open your form you do it something like this:

```
var form1 = new MyDialog();

if(form1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
  return; //abort the operation, the user cancelled/closed the first modal

MyResult form1Data = form1.Result;  //get your actual data from that modal form.
//...and then on with your second modal
```

So you collect the data from the modal(s) as you go along, aborting if any are cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using a modal window!

If you call

```
var dialog = new DialogWindow();
If (dialog.ShowDialog(mainWindow) == DialogResult.OK) {
    use the result of the dialog window
}
```

the dialog window will be modal, which means that you cannot access other windows while it is open.

With the following code, both windows are accessible at the same time. The problem is, however, that the code in the main window is not paused while the dialog runs.

```
var dialog = new DialogWindow();
dialog.Show(mainWindow);
You cannot use the result of the dialog window here!
```

Therefore you need a way to communicate the completion of the dialog to the main window. I suggest creating an event in the dialog window for this purpose

```
public class ProductResultEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ProductResultEventArgs(List<Product> products)
    {
        Products = products;
    }

    public List<Product> Products { get; private set; }
}
```

In the dialog window

```
public event EventHandler<ProductResultEventArgs> ProductsChosen;

private void OnProductsChosen(List<Product> products)
{
    var eh = ProductsChosen;
    if (eh != null) {
        eh(this, new ProductResultEventArgs(products));
    }
}

private BtnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnProductsChosen(somehow get the product list);
}
```

In the main window you can do something like this

```
var dialog = new DialogWindow();
dialog.ProcuctsChosen += Dialog_ProductsChosen
dialog.Show(mainWindow);
```

and create a handler

```
private Dialog_ProductsChosen(object sender, ProductResultEventArgs e)
{
     use e.Products here
}
```

---

Note: Passing the main window as parameter to `ShowDialog` or `Show` makes the main window owner of the dialog. This means that the dialog window will always stay in front of the main window and cannot disappear behind it. If you minimize the main window, this will minimize the dialog window as well.

Comment: But is it a way to get it to automatically add the control in the main window with data from the modal window in silverlight application? I ask because I do not long'm using C #

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Most people who answered here assumed that the problem was about passing data from a dialog window to a main window and about accessibility of modal windows. Now you are asking something completely different (adding a control) and mention Silverlight for the first time. You should add a Silverlight tag to your question, as this requires completely different solutions than WinForms, for instance.